# is there anyway i can hear sound when i remote into my computer

Tags: remote-desktop, audio

i am using remote desktop and i want to see if there is anyway i can hear the sound through my "remoted" computer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First ensure that you are using the [latest version](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/951616) of the Terminal Services Client (6.1).  This is the built-in software in Windows that lets you connect using Remote Desktop.

It is just a quick change of a setting in the properties for the connection, see below:

[image]

If you already have a shortcut on your desktop, simply right-click it and select `Edit` to bring up the properties dialog box.

Comment: +1 for beating me while I was trying to type the instructions.